# How can I use Cloud Functions to bypass Firestore Cloud security rules if I'm using custom authentication?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm not using Firebase Auth, instead AWS Amplify Cognito for my Flutter mobile app. How can I bypass the security rules with Cloud Functions to still have secure access to Cloud Firestore?

request.auth doesn't unfortunately work for other auth services, like AWS Amplify Cognito.

Comment: "request.auth doesn't unfortunately work for custom auth methods" `request.auth` is populated when a user signs in with Firebase Authentication, including when they [sign in with custom authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/custom-auth). In fact that is probably the best option to use here.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for the confusion, I edited the original body of the question - what I meant with custom auth was auth from third party services not Firebase.

Comment: Yup, that's what custom auth would allow you to do: sign the user in with Firebase based on their established Cognito credentials, so that their information becomes available in the `request.auth` variable in your rues. Check the link for full info.

Comment: Thank you so much @FrankvanPuffelen for your response, I greatly appreciate it. However, even with custom tokens, I'm still using Firebase Auth. I'm not allowed to use Firebase Auth at all in any shape or form even with custom tokens, because I'm working from the EU. Firebase Auth is not GDPR compliant and therefore, even custom tokens are not an options. I was wondering if there was an option to bypass Firebase Auth in general, because custom tokens could still be identifiable info when it comes to EU users. Nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: "Firebase Auth is not GDPR compliant and therefore, even custom tokens are not an options." When you mint your tokens, Firebase Auth stores (afaik) nothing more than  the information you store in that token.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for putting up with my concerns @Frank van Puffelen. Does that mean you can't trace back any tokens to the individual users, I.e. they are not identifiable info? Thanks!